# Python - displaying conic sequence with only 4 digit sequencing

Tags: python, list, numbers

I am writing a program to determine the conic sequence of a user's inputted data set, for example - **[0000,1,2222,9999]**,

I was struggling with sequencing the conic sequence using only a 4 digit classification, instead of the typical 8/16 binary approaches.

---

I have tried this:

```
for t in permutations(numbers, 4):
print(''.join(t))
```

But it does not assign a unique value to the inputted data, and instead overrides previous ones.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: `for i in range(10000)`, or use itertools combinations

Comment: That doesn't help, it just prints the number list 10000 times. I want to show all 4 digit combinations, sorry if I was not clear enough

Comment: did you actually try what I've suggested? `i` will become all the values between `[0 - 9999]`

Comment: to add to @Mahrkeenerh before printing convert the number to string and use `.zfill(4)` (for performance probably do it only if the number is below a 1000)

Comment: Can you please make an answer showing what the command should look like for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your list only contains the numbers 0 through 9 and you're looping over that list, printing the content as you go, it will only print 0 through 9.

Since all possible combinations (or rather permutations, because that's what you're asking about) of the normal decimal digits are just the numbers 0 through 9999, you could do this instead:

```
for i in range(10000):
    print(i)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range for more on `range()`.

But that doesn't print numbers like '0' as '0000'. To do that (in Python 3, which is probably what you should be using):

```
for i in range(10000):
    print(f"{i:04d}")
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings for more on f-strings.

Of course, if you need permutations of something other than digits, you can't use this method. You'd do something like this instead:

```
from itertools import permutations

xs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

for t in permutations(xs, 4):
    print(''.join(t))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations for more on `permutations()` and the difference with `combinations()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this, if you want to change some information by the future :

```py
import math

NUMBERS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
DIGITS = 4
MAX_ITERS = int(math.pow(len(NUMBERS), DIGITS))

for i in range(MAX_ITERS):
    print(f"{i:04d}")
```

Comment: this sounds overly complicated for a simple issue.

Comment: also, `len(NUMBERS) ** DIGITS` works just fine, no need for `math`